# rsync failed verification -- update retained

Tags: rsync

I want to transfer a file (67GB) from a university sever to my local machine. I first connect to the university VPN and then connect to the server.

I ran the following command on macOS:

```
rsync -rvhP --progress --append --no-owner --no-group /Volumes/eutops/raw-data/nanopore/pilot/data/FR11441102_ST-00005257/FR11441102_ST-00005257_BAM /Volumes/data/data/nanopore
```

and got the following error:

```
building file list ... 
2 files to consider
FR11441102_ST-00005257_BAM/
FR11441102_ST-00005257_BAM/FR11441102_ST-00005257.pass.bam
      67.27G 100%    1.78MB/s   10:00:13 (xfer#1, to-check=0/2)
rsync: read errors mapping "/Volumes/eutops/raw-data/nanopore/pilot/data/FR11441102_ST-00005257/FR11441102_ST-00005257_BAM/FR11441102_ST-00005257.pass.bam": Operation timed out (60)
WARNING: FR11441102_ST-00005257_BAM/FR11441102_ST-00005257.pass.bam failed verification -- update retained (will try again).
file has vanished: "/Volumes/eutops/raw-data/nanopore/pilot/data/FR11441102_ST-00005257/FR11441102_ST-00005257_BAM/FR11441102_ST-00005257.pass.bam"

sent 67.28G bytes  received 5.19M bytes  1.84M bytes/sec
total size is 67.27G  speedup is 1.00
rsync error: some files could not be transferred (code 23) at /AppleInternal/Library/BuildRoots/11aa8fb2-5f4b-11ee-bc7f-926038f30c31/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/rsync/rsync/main.c(996) [sender=2.6.9]
```

The VPN had disconnected after a certain amount of time. When I rerun the command again it starts from 0%.

I also tried to run the same command on ubuntu. It chugs along nicely for an hour or two and then the transfer speed increases dramatically (~300MB/s), the progress jumps dramatically, and then I get a total system crash.

How can I transfer my file?